# how to export xwiki pages from apache Fop

Tags: java, xwiki

i have created pages in xwiki , but images are not getting exported for in case of multiple page. for single page export image is getting exported.
 tables also not exported in correct format,
so i downloaded apache Fop but  i do not know how to export xwiki pages from FOP and how to  merge those PDF in fop.

Comment: Edit your question and show us what you've already tried. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the guide lines

Comment: If images are not exported in multi-page export, it is probably a XWiki bug. If I remember correctly this is a relatively new feature. Maybe it helps to report this as a bug in the XWiki bug tracker.